# bower install not recognizing local npm package?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm, bower

I am getting the following error upon runing bower install.

```
$ bower install
module.js:340
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'minimist'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous>     (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v5.1.0/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-config/node_modules/optimist/index.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
```

I have "minimist" installed as a **local** npm package but not globally. Is there any way to get bower to recognize the local package and avoid installing minimist globally?

Comment: Are you sure that you installed `minimist`? Please post your `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

Running `npm install -S minimist` in a CLI from your project root directory should solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, before trying your solution, I upgraded to bower 1.6.8 (from 1.6.6) and I can no longer reproduce the problem (and hence check whether this would have worked).

Comment: I don't mind. Great to hear you solved your problem!